# usort php, ordernar tabela do brasilerão

Tags: php, array

Amigos, tenho um array com a tabela do brasileirão, nela contem nome do time, vitorias, saldo de gols, gols pró, etc..

Eu gostaria de ordenar o array usando o critério do brasileirão, pontos > vitorias > saldo de gols > gols pró > gols contra.

se os dados estivessem no mysql eu conseguiria assim.

```
pts_time DESC, vit_time DESC, sg_time DESC, gp_time DESC, gc_time ASC
```

e no array? alguma luz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando a função array_multisort()

Exemplo

```
/*
pts -> points (pontos)
win -> victories (vitórias)
gd -> goals difference (saldo de gols)
gp -> goals pro (gols pró)
gc -> goals conceded (gols contra)

Cada chave do array $data representa um time.
Para que a função array_multisort() preserve as chaves do array $data, as mesmas devem ser do tipo string.
*/
$data['a'] = array('pts' => 67, 'win' => 7, 'gd' => 2, 'gp' => 10, 'gc' => 8);
$data['b'] = array('pts' => 86, 'win' => 1, 'gd' => 8, 'gp' => 20, 'gc' => 12);
$data['c'] = array('pts' => 85, 'win' => 6, 'gd' => 10, 'gp' => 22, 'gc' => 12);
$data['d'] = array('pts' => 98, 'win' => 2, 'gd' => 5, 'gp' => 15, 'gc' => 10);
$data['e'] = array('pts' => 86, 'win' => 6, 'gd' => 3, 'gp' => 14, 'gc' => 11);
$data['f'] = array('pts' => 67, 'win' => 7, 'gd' => 2, 'gp' => 10, 'gc' => 6);

// Obtendo a lista de colunas baseado no primeiro array.
$arr_keys = array_keys($data['a']);

// Assinando os dados para cada coluna em arrays independentes
foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
    foreach ($arr_keys as $k) {
        $arr[$k][$key]  = $row[$k];
    }
}

// Onde a mágica acontece
array_multisort(
            $arr[$arr_keys[0]], SORT_DESC, SORT_NUMERIC, 
            $arr[$arr_keys[1]], SORT_DESC, SORT_NUMERIC, 
            $arr[$arr_keys[2]], SORT_DESC, SORT_NUMERIC, 
            $arr[$arr_keys[3]], SORT_DESC, SORT_NUMERIC, 
            $arr[$arr_keys[4]], SORT_ASC, SORT_NUMERIC, 
            $data);

// Teste do resultado
print_r($data);
```

Esse exemplo foi baseado num dos exemplos da documentação:
http://php.net/array_multisort

Comment: Muito obrigado, consegui resolver com seu exemplo, parabéns e novamente obrigado.

Comment: Amigo, realizando isso surgiu outro problema, em caso de empate em todas as condições, na tabela do brasileirão os times precisam estar na mesma posição, por exemplo 7º santos e corinthians, e não 7º, 8º como o array faz, alguma ideia?

Comment: adicione outro parâmetro de desempate... qual o critério da CBF para esses casos? Pois é, adicione tal critério.. Para o fluminense chama-se tapetão.. hehehe